# Open Browser with URL WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, .net-core-3.1

How to open an external browser by hyperlink, in a browser it would be target='_top'.

What is the code in a WPF netcore 3.1 app?

1. Use CommandParameter

   ```
   <TextBlock>
       <Hyperlink CommandParameter="{Binding ExternalURL}"
                  Command="{Binding NavHomeViewCommand}" >Open in Browser ...
       </Hyperlink>
   </TextBlock>
   ```
2. Change DelegateCommand to use object parameter (using the prismlibrary mvvm pattern)

   ```
   navHomeViewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(NavHomeView);
   ```
3. Command Properties:

   ```
   public string ExternalURL{ get => "https://www.google.com/";}
   private readonly ICommand navHomeViewCommand;
   public ICommand NavHomeViewCommand
   {
       get { return navHomeViewCommand; }
   }
   ```
4. Open a browser

   ```
   private void NavHomeView(object ID)
   {
       if(obj is string destinationurl)
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://google.com");  //???????   
   }
   ```

An exception is thrown 'unknown executable'.

Comment: See if that solves your problem

Comment: .netcore3.1 is not your everyday WPF

Comment: none of the answers in the 'duplicate' question worked. After much trial and error the resulting 'hack' is: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", "/C start" + " " + destinationurl);

Comment: Ill reopen this question, and you can self answer

Comment: You also might want to tag this. .netcore 3.1

Comment: Also 2, this might be worth a small bounty, if you show everything that hasnt work, there might be people out there that have had the same issue and know a better work around

Answer (score 8):

Solution that opens Windows OS level default Browser with the specified URL. Recommended via [WPF Github issue 2566](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2566#issuecomment-586351870):

```
        var destinationurl = "https://www.bing.com/";
        var sInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(destinationurl)
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
        };
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sInfo);
```

**OLD:**
The solution that opens a silent CMD prompt and opens the Windows OS default browser:

```
    private void NavHomeView(object ID)
    {
        //return;
        if (IDis string destinationurl)
        {
            var link = new Uri(destinationurl);
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = $"/c start {link.AbsoluteUri}"
            };
            Process.Start(psi);
        ...
```

but if your intent is to package the app using the MSIX packaging project type and put it in the Windows Store, then you'll [fail certification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) for using CMD.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe", "https://www.google.fr");
```

or if you don't know path of file .exe of navigator

```
var UrlExterne = "https://www.google.fr";
var filetemp = $"{Path.GetTempFileName()}.url";
try
{
     using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filetemp))
     {
          sw.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
          sw.WriteLine($"URL={UrlExterne}");
          sw.Close();
      }
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filetemp);
 }
 finally
 {
     if(File.Exists(filetemp))
          File.Delete(filetemp);
 }
```